# Arduino Sketch: NodeMCU compilation error

Tags: arduino-ide, sketch, nodemcu, compilation-errors

Every time I try to compile a program written in Arduino IDE 1.8.5 for NodeMCU (LoLIN version v3), I get the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 115200, 4M (3M SPIFFS)"

C:\Users\sumeetpatil\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar: unable to rename 'C:\Users\SUMEET~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_831529/arduino.ar'; reason: File exists

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I have tried reinstalling several times, but I just can't get ahead of this step.

Comment: what else does turning on the verbose output say? it might be a lib that's not compat.

Answer (score 1):

> Do a full uninstall of Arduino, then delete the Arduino folder and
>   Arduino15 (back them up first if you have any sketches in there!!!!),
>   as well as **any Arduino folders under Temp**. Make sure the folders and
>   all contents are really gone, reboot and try again if not. Then, do a
>   clean install of the IDE.

Cited from [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2987).